# Does Mauritania require a visa for children travelling with their parents?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, children, mauritania

Does Mauritania require a visa for children travelling with their parents?
Does it matter if the children have separate passports? Does it matter if the children are registered in their parents' passport?

Comment: How old are the children?

Answer (score 2):

The [Islamic Republic of Mauritania](http://www.mauritanianembassy.org.uk/mauritanian_visa.php) makes no apparent exclusions to its comprehensive visa policy, per its London Embassy visa information:

> Please note that all types of visas for all nationalities are now obtainable on arrival at Nouakchott airport and at the border.
>
> **Visitors need to ensure they comply with the following requirements:**

- Passports must be valid for at least 6 months.
- Invitation letter for business travellers.
- Hotel booking and or letter from Mauritanian host.

The page also lists visa fees, according to country of origin and length of stay.

As not all of its [34 embassies and 25 consulates](https://www.embassypages.com/mauritania) have email contact, you may want to send an enquiry to London info@mauritanianembassy.org.uk for clarification in advance of travels.